# jQuery isn't working despite no error showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm relatively new to jQuery, and I'm experiencing some trouble with it. My assignment is to redesign a webpage and implement certain features using jQuery. Right now, I'm trying to create a dropdown menu for each "button" in my nav bar. When I hover over a "button" in the nav bar, a dropdown menu should show up. My jQuery appears to be working but the dropdown menu isn't showing up on the webpage...

Here is my  code:

```
<head>
    <title>Team Imperial College: Project Description</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

Here is the HTML code (nav bar and dropdown menu code):

```
<ul class="nav_bar">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="ourteam.php" class="drop_item">Our Team</a>
        <ul class="dropdown_content">
            <li><a href="meettheteam.php">Meet the Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="attributes">Attributes</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="file:///C:/Users/amyz1/HTMLClass/p2[Amy,%20az287]/index.html">Our Project</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="modelling.php">Modelling</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="software.php">Software</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="documentation.php">Documentation</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="humancentereddesign.php">Human Centered Design</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    background-color: #EDDBDB;
}

.nav_bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #F3F3FF;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nav_bar li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 24px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 105%;
}

/*dropdown menu code*/
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F3F3FF;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown_content li a {
   color: #000000;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
}

.dropdown_content li a:hover {
    background-color: #DBDBE5;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
    display: block;
}
```

/*dropdown menu code*/

And here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
       $('.dropdown_content').toggle(); 
    });

    $('.dropdown_content li a').hover();
});
```

Please help! Help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This code is doing exactly what you told it to do.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/16wjwjow/ - its doing exactly what you told it to.

Comment: What is occurring,  or not occurring that is causing you to believe it is broken?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: No errors in the console...I posted some more code below that I'm wondering is causing a problem.

Comment: What is the error you are experiencing?  i.e. dropdown not appearing or it is appearing to far down the page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First test i would make is make dropdown_content visible since begin, to make sure the toggle function works.

Then you can do this test:

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function() {
       $('.dropdown_content').toggle(); 
       alert('Over here');
    });
```

Check how many times "Over here" appears.

Having those answers will help you on the way out of this.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like my jQuery is working. I'm actually wondering if some of my other code (HTML, CSS) is causing the error; I posted below.

Comment: Try $('.dropdown_content').show();

 $('.dropdown').blur(function() {
       $('.dropdown_content').hide(); 
       alert('Over here');
    });

Comment: Sorry I didn't correctly specify the issue I'm experiencing. I just edited my post, but my issue is that the jQuery appears to be working but the dropdown menu isn't visible when I hover over the 'Our Team' button...

Answer (score 0):

it seems you haven't addressed the event on mouse out. try changing this code:

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown_content').toggle(); 
});
```

to this:

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown_content').toggle(); 
}, function() {
    $('.dropdown_content').toggle(); 
});
```

if you want it only to be trigger on when entering it do this:

```
$('.dropdown').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.dropdown_content').toggle(); 
});
```

i suggest looking at [this](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) for better detail.

**EDIT:**
how toggle works is by making the element's display variable to none that essentially means that it does not exist on the page anymore.

if you wanted it to toggle on hover, you would need to toggle the opacity between 0 and 1.

best method:
create a css class

```
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

edit JQuery code
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
       $('.dropdown').toggleClass('.dropdown', "hidden");

       //you can use this for multiple elements
       //$(this).toggleClass(this, "hidden");
    });

    $('.dropdown_content li a').hover();
});
```

deprecated method:
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
    $('.dropdown').hover(function() {
       $('.dropdown_content').toggle(() => {
         $('.dropdown_content').css({opacity: "0"});
       }, () => {
         $('.dropdown_content').css({opacity: "1"});
       }); 
    });

    $('.dropdown_content li a').hover();
});
```

note: () => {} is shorthand for a callback function

Comment: Sorry I didn't correctly specify the issue I'm experiencing. I just edited my post, but my issue is that the jQuery appears to be working but the dropdown menu isn't visible when I hover over the 'Our Team' button...

Comment: i have updated my answer to fit your edit. I suggest you take a look at what JQuery does with css to better understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (jQuery) {
    alert(“jquery is loaded”);
} else {
    alert(” Not loaded”);
}
```

Comment: Why might this be an issue for the OP?